# Placing parent tag name in jQuery nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html file of about 100 elements. In my javascript file, I have a var that holds all elements in the html document using jQuery. I then have a var that holds all elements that are text nodes in the html document. What I am wanting to do is for every non text node, create a new child node and set the innerHTML to its parents tag name. How would I go about doing that?

```
//All elements
var elements = $("*")

//Text Nodes only
var textNodes = elements.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
});
```

Comment: Why not `return this.nodeType != 3` and process all the non text nodes?

Comment: Why do you need `textNodes` at all?

Comment: @BatScream How would I go about creating a new child node if I were to do that? I am COMPLETELY new to jQuery so I don't know a whole lot.

Comment: Universal selector selects all the Elements, i.e. nodes that have nodeType of 1, the filter is not needed. `$('*').append(function () {
    return '<span>' + this.tagName + '</span>';
})` ? http://jsfiddle.net/yg8c5t5q/

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is it for debug purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a little bit cleaner solution which would not pollute DOM tree with extra elements (there can be a lot of elements targeted with `*` selector). Why not make use of some CSS to display tag name using `:after` pseudo elements?

First set actual tag names for every element and then use this CSS to display them:

```js
$("*").attr('data-tag', function() {
    return this.tagName;
});
```

```css
*:after {
    content: attr(data-tag);
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Test content</div>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for you help but @Vohumans solution was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but this will take find all nodes not containing text, and append a  to them containing their node name.

```
//All elements
var elements = $("*")

//Text Nodes only
var nodes = elements.contents().filter(function (i) {
    if ( this.nodeType !== 3 ) {
      var el = document.createElement('div');
          el.innerHTML = this.nodeName;
      this.appendChild(el)
    }
});
```